# Pattern match agains Num in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function that takes a `Num` and does different things depending on whether it is a float, double or integer. The only way I have found to do this is using a type class however this seems very ugly. Is there a way to match against any type of number and so do different things depending on which one of 3 instances of Num it is? Something like

```
myFun :: (Num a) => a -> T
myFun n = case n of
  n :: Int -> something for ints
  n :: Float -> something for floats
  n :: Double -> something for doubles
```

rather than

```
class MyClass a where
  myFun :: (Num a) => a -> T
```

with instances for `Int`, `Float`, `Double`?

Comment: What is that "something for ints" ? Is it an IO action or some other pure computation ?

Comment: There are many more instances of Num. I wonder whether you really need to do a case over the possible types -- this is a code smell, and seems an XY problem. What is the general problem you want to solve with this approach?

Comment: Type classes like `Num` are open, meaning you can't predict ahead of time what types someone might try to pass to `myFun`, so your `case` expression can never be complete. `class Num a => MyClass a` is the right approach. Another user cannot extend the definition of `myFun` to accommodate their type `Foo` that has a `Num` instance, but they can declare a `MyClass` instance for `Foo`.

Comment: By the way! It's worth nothing that this is a very very weird Haskell function, and there is a good chance that you're doing something that isn't really meant to be done in Haskell or is strongly non-idiomatic.  You're basically definiting three different functions on three different types.  Why on earth would you need to call them all using the same name?  What situation are you using this in?

Comment: that's an interesting question Justin, it is for a Riemann client. A message has a metric field but due to the serialization (protobuffers) there are actually 3 possible fields, one for ints, one for floats and one for doubles. I want an api where you just set the metric, regardless of what type of number it is, and the correct field will be set on the protobuffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another, admittedly not pretty way to do it is this:

```
import Data.Typeable

myFunc :: (Typeable a, Num a, Show a) => a -> String
myFunc x 
    | typeOf x == typeOf (0:: Int) = "Its an Int: " ++ show x
    | typeOf x == typeOf (0:: Float) = "Its a Float: " ++ show x
    | typeOf x == typeOf (0:: Double) = "Its a Double: " ++ show x
```

The weakness of this solution is, that there are way more instances of `Num a` than the three used in the above function. Hence, at one point or another, someone will e.g. call `myFunc 42` and be surprised it is an exception, as there is no case handling `Integer`, which is also a `Num a`.

Using your own typeclass, in contrast helps narrowing down the set of usable types and thus helps preventing exceptions.

> *Main> myFunc (42 :: Int)
>   "Its an Int: 42"
>   *Main> myFunc (42 :: Float)
>   "Its a Float: 42.0"
>   *Main> myFunc (42 :: Double)
>   "Its a Double: 42.0"
>   *Main> myFunc 42
>   "*** Exception: Main.hs:(11,1)-(14,66): Non-exhaustive patterns in function myFunc

Comment: @leftaroundabout Others said it already. The whole idea is a code smell, sort of. Me, personally, I would go with the instances of the type class. If ``Int 42`` worked, i.e. if it had a type constructor, pattern matching as such could work. Would be nice if someone explained, why the primitive types do not have one.

Comment: While it is indeed bad practice, this is the only answer that directly answers the questions, i.e. how to do this thing without writing type class instances. I think this answer should be on top.

Comment: I marked this as the answer since it has the most explanation and discussion, thanks guys!

Comment: After playing around, the problem with type classes is that I can't do `myFunc 42` as it is also ambiguous.

Comment: @BitTickler You can regard `42` as a constructor for the type `Int` -- at least morally. Indeed you can construct an `Int` just writing `42` and you can even pattern match on that `case n of 42 -> ...`. Under the hood there's some magic, but it's reasonable. What this question asks for has nothing to do with numeric types, though. It asks about how to break parametricity, and checks what the type `a` is, which can only be done using `Typeable`. That approach should not be taken lightly, as you point out above.

Answer (score 7):

According to my reading, this is the textbook application of type classes:

```
module Main where

class Num a => Funnable a where
    myFun :: a -> a

instance Funnable Int where
    myFun = id

instance Funnable Float where
    myFun = (+ 2)

instance Funnable Double where
    myFun = (+ 1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ myFun (1 :: Int)
    print $ myFun (1 :: Float)
    print $ myFun (1 :: Double)
```

Gives:

```
$ stack exec example
1
3.0
2.0
```

Type classes will also provide you with a *compile-time* type error when used incorrectly. For instance, suppose we had skipped the instance declaration for `Double`:

```
src/Main.hs:14:13: error:
    • No instance for (Funnable Double) arising from a use of ‘myFun’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘myFun (1 :: Double)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ myFun (1 :: Double)
      In the expression: do { print $ myFun (1 :: Double) }
```

Comment: Looks like I'll stick to type classes then. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed. This will provide type errors whenever used improperly, e.g. on another numeric type. By comparison, using `Typeable` and safe casts will generate runtime errors. Pushing errors to compile time, when reasonably possible, is very idiomatic in Haskell.

Answer (score 6):

You can model something like this:

```
data MyNum
    = MDouble Double
    | MInt Int
    | MFloat Float
    deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)

handle :: MyNum -> IO ()
handle (MDouble x) = putStrLn "This is double"
handle (MFloat x) = putStrLn "This is float"
handle (MInt x) = putStrLn "This is int"
```

Infact a similar type of abstraction has been used in the [library bson](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.3/bson-0.3.2.3/Data-Bson.html#t:Value) for modelling it's `Value` type.